# Firebase orderByChild() is not ordering numerically

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to order user points through Firebase's orderByChild() query method. I can't seem to wrap my head around it entirely because I'm a Typescript/Firebase newbie and so I've been using a lot of example codes.

My Firebase JSON looks like this:

```js
{
  "users" : {         
    "hJfEgXkyaKPckchL3kx8rpZ58Ew2" : {
      "-LV6c8E5rRD4_mQqsb6Q" : {
        "grade" : 11,
        "name" : "Lin Manuel Miranda",
        "points" : 100
      }
    },
    "mlIBrdjT8CfIURQEAhLFPzzUFQg1" : {
      "-LV7I6d8LeuWFLH5MRKy" : {
        "grade" : 12,
        "name" : "Emily Blunt",
        "points" : 20
      }
    }
 // "userID" : {
 //    "-firebase-generated-id": {
 //        "grade" : number,
 //        "name" : string,
 //        "points" : number
 //    }
 //  }
  }
}
```

My code, albeit a bit messy, is running the way it is because I need to retrieve the specific keys to reference the database... So, instead I am trying to push all the information into a new array and then displaying the array inside the html.

```js
// ts file

export class Tab1Page {
  name: string;
  grade: number;
  points: number;
  empList: Array<{name: string, grade: number, points: number}> = [];

  constructor(
    private db: AngularFireDatabase
  ) {
        // the variable pkey here is a reference to the userID
        const keyRef = firebase.database().ref('/users/' + pkey);
        const ref2 = keyRef.orderByChild('points').limitToLast(7);

        ref2.once('value').then(function(snap2) {
          snap2.forEach(function (childSnap2) {
            const key = childSnap2.key;
            const List = this.empList;
            const firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('/users/' + pkey + '/' + key);
            
            firebaseRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
              const name = snapshot.val().name;
              const grade = snapshot.val().grade;
              const points = snapshot.val().points;
              List.push({
                name: name,
                grade: grade,
                points: points
              });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }

}
```

The problem is, no matter how I edit the code, the orderByChild() query returns my users in the order that they are in the database, NOT by their point values.

**UPDATE**
For those who in the future may be struggling with this as well, the way I fixed it (with Frank's help), was instead of setting the User's ID as part of the JSON path, I pushed the ID as one of the childs:

```js
{
  "users" : {
    "-LVL5EWo3MBnLdAv0fFf" : {
      "ID" : "g4V3ZmBRJfcN2WSeoSPuPbxl3o72",
      "grade" : 11,
      "name" : "Caroline Choi",
      "points" : 10
    },
    "-LVL69jiTxb5MprLpjrK" : {
      "ID" : "21XBQvWXtuayo1ZxxmS566phDv13",
      "grade" : 12,
      "name" : "Emily Blunt",
      "points" : 0
    }
  }
}
```

This allowed the query to run with no errors.

Comment: Can you reduce the code to a single query (the one that is giving you problems) and just log the keys+scores? That will make it much easier to help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi Frank, I've updated the code (above), but let me know if you'd like me to reduce it down a little more. What do you mean by "just log the keys+scores"? Thank you!

Comment: I might simply not understand what you're trying to do. Can you update your question to contains a snippet of your real JSON (as text, no screenshots), so that I can try it myself? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I've now added the real JSON. Also, because I minimised my code to only the troubling portion, let me explain where I'm going with it. Essentially, I needed to get a reference to both the userIDs and the ids of the stuff nested under the userIDs, so I was running a query twice.

Comment: When you attach a listener to a location, the snapshot you get contains *all* data under that location. So as far as I can see, you don't need nested listeners. But each of your users now only has a single score node, so how can we see that the results for a specific user are not in the right order?

Comment: Can you try adding startAt(0)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Could you elaborate a little more on your question? I'm still new to Firebase so I don't have a firm grasp on all the terminology.

Comment: The JSON you shared has two users, each with a single score under them. Since your code does `firebase.database().ref('/users/' + pkey)`, you're getting the scores for a single user, so only a single score.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I think it does work in my full code, which I have linked here: https://github.com/carolinechoi/stackOverflowCode/blob/master/tab1.page.ts. If you console.log(name + grade + points), the code returns both users.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, and I apologise for the frustratingly messy code haha... I'm going off of YouTube tutorials and such.

Comment: No need to apologize, but I won't be able to help further without more information. I highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to learn how to make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm not really sure what the problem is, I set up a little test of my own for you to look at.

JSON:

```
{
  "-LV6c8E5rRD4_mQqsb6Q" : {
    "grade" : 11,
    "name" : "Lin Manuel Miranda",
    "points" : 100
  },
  "-LV6c8E5rRD4_mQqsb6Z" : {
    "grade" : 42,
    "name" : "Frank van Puffelen",
    "points" : 80
  }
}
```

Live JSON: https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/54018652/users/hJfEgXkyaKPckchL3kx8rpZ58Ew2.json?print=pretty

code:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("/54018652");

var keyRef = ref.child("users/hJfEgXkyaKPckchL3kx8rpZ58Ew2");
var ref2 = keyRef.orderByChild('points').limitToLast(7);

ref2.once('value').then(function(snap2) {
  snap2.forEach(function (childSnap2) {
    var key = childSnap2.key;
    var points = childSnap2.child("points").val();
    console.log(key+": "+points);
  });
});
```

Working code: https://jsbin.com/ceyejil/edit?js,console

When I run this code against this JSON it prints:

> -LV6c8E5rRD4_mQqsb6Z: 80
>
> -LV6c8E5rRD4_mQqsb6Q: 100

So these are the two nodes under the location that I'm querying in the order of their points value.

Comment: Frank, I'm marking your response as the answer because it helped me understand why my code wasn't working. Additionally, I updated my question to reflect how I modified my JSON to match yours (and how then the query worked beautifully). Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear caroline.

Answer (score 0):

The case is that you're using the `.once()` method and the Firebase Realtime queries only works with the `.on()` method, as you can see in the [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query?hl=pt-br). So changing your references where you use the `.orderByChild()` to the `.on()` should make it work.

Also I advise you to learn how to structure your database in a better way, your code is so complicated for something that must be simple and you're making 3 calls to Firebase (or 3 levels, since there's a forEach with many other requests). You must consider learning how to work better with the Firebase Realtime or your code will grow harder and harder to give maintenance and to read.

Comment: "The case is that you're using the .once() method and the Firebase Realtime queries only works with the .on() method" Firebase queries work the same across `on` and `once`. The only difference between the two is that `once()` automatically stops listening after it gets the first results from the database.

Comment: @GabrielBarreto As Frank pointed out, I believe .once() works the same way. And yes, my code definitely needs to be simpler, but again, I'm a newbie and can't really figure out how to reduce it efficiently.